# Is there a way to deleting a file during uninstallation of an APK

Tags: android, apk

I'm working on a project that is made up of a set of applications installed onto an android device.  Each applications places certain files in a shared directory in local storage.

Is there a way in android to have the files that belonged to a particular application deleted when the APK is uninstalled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not if you have them "in a shared directory in local storage" (where I am translating "local storage" as being what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html)).

Files located in per-app directories, like `getExternalFilesDir()`, "belong" to the app and are deleted when the app is uninstalled.

Files located elsewhere on external storage "belong" to the user and are retained when an app is uninstalled.

Comment: Just to clarify your answer, there's no way to hook a custom action into an APK uninstall?

Comment: @SteveMitcham: Correct. Apps cannot get control on an uninstall event, to prevent malicious activity, such as trying to prevent the uninstall from happening.